# Remote 3D Model Download

Tags: javascript, php, 3d

Normally you would load a 3D model in the browser. Once it has loaded you can (for example) download an image of the model. Is there a way to have the 3D model loaded permanently on a server so you could make calls to the server at any time and download an image on the server?

I'm using sketchfab.

Example of a loaded 3D model and download.
https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/examples?sample=Screenshot%20Save

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it, but it's probably not a good idea. Generally, processing-intensive tasks like 3D rendering are offloaded to the client machine so that you don't need to stand up a rendering farm and a fat upload pipe just to stream on-demand 3D renders to clients. If anything you'd want to pre-render a set number of angles in advance.

Comment: Hi Sammitch, thanks for your reply. I can pre-render if needed. However, I'm amazed at the speed that an image is created and downloaded, less than a second. This fast, on-demand image creation would be very useful in some projects. Can you shed any light on how I would do this?  Maybe it would not be practical but I would love to try!

Comment: Why would this question that's only been viewed 8 times be maked for close? Maybe someone could point me in the correct direction and this would be very helpfull to me.

Comment: The question is marked for closure because it is not canonically answerable within the confines of StackOverflow's format. A question should ideally be about and contain program code, and the answer should also focus on the code, ideally with an _objectively_ correct answer. Nebulous questions about the possibility/practicality of doing a thing are far outside this and will attract opinionated arguments and links to external libraries/tutorials, none of which are particularly helpful in the context of what StackOverflow is/does.

Comment: and yes, an image might be rendered in "less than a second", but in centralizing this on-demand task to a server/service you will eventually reach the case that you have more rendering requests that you have CPU time to service. I'm not saying that it's not doable, only that it is inadvisable without extensive consideration.

Comment: Thanks Sammitch,  I'm not sure where to go with this question as I have no idea how to go about implementing it. I understand that it might not work under heavy load but I would like to try, just for fun.

Comment: I don't either, but for a start: Whatever way that it is done client-side in javascript is probably equally applicable server-side in node. Not likely particularly efficient, but a start.

Comment: Thanks Sammitch, I appresiate your time.